# Error while manually compiling Coder MEX code in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I need to edit the code from the MATLAB Coder for a MEX function.
So before editing it, I thought I should try compiling it as it is to see if this works fine. If not, I would have to solve that problem first before editing the code.

And here I am since its not working. I get errors since because of "undefined references" and I dont know why.
99% of the errors are because some `emlrtAlias` or other functions have undefinded references. Those functions are in the `emlrt.h` file, but I can include the folder in the path, I can copy the fild in the directory where all the .cpp's are, its not working and I dont know why.

Here is the code I am compiling with as well as the errors:

```
mex('-v','-compatibleArrayDims',['-I',matlabroot,'\extern\include'],'*.cpp')

Verbose mode is on.
... Looking for compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'MW_MINGW64_LOC' ...Yes ('C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset').
... Looking for file 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset' ...Yes.
... Looking for environment variable 'MW_MINGW64_LOC' ...Yes ('C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset').
... Executing command 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -dumpmachine' ...Yes ('x86_64-w64-mingw32').
... Looking for environment variable 'MW_MINGW64_LOC' ...Yes ('C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset').
... Executing command 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -dumpversion' ...Yes ('6.3.0').
Found installed compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
Set PATH = C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\simulink\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\lib\win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16-HDRI;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IncrediBuild;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
Set INCLUDE = C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\include;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.3.0\include;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\x86_64-w64-mingw32;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\backward;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\include;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.3.0\include;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\x86_64-w64-mingw32;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\backward;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include;
Set LIB = C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\lib;;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\lib;;
Set MW_TARGET_ARCH = win64;win64;
Set LIBPATH = C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\lib\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\lib\win64;
Options file details
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Compiler location: C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset
    Options file: C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2020b\mex_C++_win64.xml
    CMDLINE2 : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -static -s -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def" C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\rt_nonfinite.obj C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_info.obj C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\cpp_mexapi_version.obj   -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -llibMatlabDataArray -llibMatlabEngine -o grain_struct_grower_para.mexw64
    CXX : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++
    COMPILER : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++
    DEFINES : -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
    MATLABMEX : -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
    CFLAGS : -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer
    CXXFLAGS : -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11
    INCLUDE : -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/simulink/include"
    CXXOPTIMFLAGS : -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG
    CXXDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    LDXX : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++
    LINKER : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++
    LDFLAGS : -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined
    LDTYPE : -shared -static
    LINKEXPORT : -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mexFunction.def"
    LINKEXPORTVER : -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def"
    LIBLOC : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64
    LINKLIBS : -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -llibMatlabDataArray -llibMatlabEngine
    LDOPTIMFLAGS : -s
    LDDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    OBJEXT : .obj
    LDEXT : .mexw64
    SETENV : set COMPILER=C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\gcc
                set CXXCOMPILER=C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++
                set COMPFLAGS=-c -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
                set CXXCOMPFLAGS=-c -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
                set OPTIMFLAGS=-O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG
                set DEBUGFLAGS=-g
                set LINKER=C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\gcc
                set CXXLINKER=C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++
                set LINKFLAGS=-m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -static -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -llibMatlabDataArray -llibMatlabEngine -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mexFunction.def"
                set LINKDEBUGFLAGS=-g
                set NAME_OUTPUT= -o "%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%"
    MINGWROOT : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset
    MINGWTARGET : x86_64-w64-mingw32
    VERSION : 6.3.0
    MATLABROOT : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b
    ARCH : win64
    SRC : "C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\grain_struct_grower_para.cpp";"C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\rt_nonfinite.cpp";"C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_info.cpp";"C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.cpp";"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp"
    OBJ : C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj;C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\rt_nonfinite.obj;C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_info.obj;C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj;C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
    OBJS : C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\rt_nonfinite.obj C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_info.obj C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\cpp_mexapi_version.obj 
    SRCROOT : C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\grain_struct_grower_para
    DEF : C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.def
    EXP : "grain_struct_grower_para.exp"
    LIB : "grain_struct_grower_para.lib"
    EXE : grain_struct_grower_para.mexw64
    ILK : "grain_struct_grower_para.ilk"
    MANIFEST : "grain_struct_grower_para.mexw64.manifest"
    TEMPNAME : grain_struct_grower_para
    EXEDIR : 
    EXENAME : grain_struct_grower_para
    OPTIM : -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG
    LINKOPTIM : -s
    CMDLINE1_0 : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\grain_struct_grower_para.cpp" -o C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj
    CMDLINE1_1 : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\rt_nonfinite.cpp" -o C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\rt_nonfinite.obj
    CMDLINE1_2 : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_info.cpp" -o C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_info.obj
    CMDLINE1_3 : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.cpp" -o C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj
    CMDLINE1_4 : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp" -o C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\grain_struct_grower_para.cpp" -o C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\rt_nonfinite.cpp" -o C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\rt_nonfinite.obj
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_info.cpp" -o C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_info.obj
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "C:\Users\Marc\Promo\Promo_matlab\linked_grains_modelCPP\codegen\mex\grain_struct_grower_para\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.cpp" -o C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32  -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp" -o C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset\bin\g++ -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -static -s -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def" C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\rt_nonfinite.obj C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_info.obj C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\cpp_mexapi_version.obj   -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -llibMatlabDataArray -llibMatlabEngine -o grain_struct_grower_para.mexw64
Error using mex
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined
reference to `emlrtAlias'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined
reference to `emlrtAlias'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined
reference to `emlrtCheckBuiltInR2012b'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined
reference to `emlrtMxGetData'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined
reference to `emlrtDestroyArray'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x89): undefined
reference to `emlrtDestroyArray'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined
reference to `emlrtDestroyArray'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0xd0): undefined
reference to `emlrtAlias'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0xdc): undefined
reference to `emlrtAlias'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x112): undefined
reference to `emlrtCheckBuiltInR2012b'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x11b): undefined
reference to `emlrtMxGetData'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x128): undefined
reference to `emlrtDestroyArray'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x131): undefined
reference to `emlrtDestroyArray'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x13a): undefined
reference to `emlrtDestroyArray'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x17b): undefined
reference to `emlrtCreateNumericArray'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\grain_struct_grower_para.obj:grain_struct_grower_para.cpp:(.text+0x189): undefined
reference to `emlrtMxSetData'
.
.
.
.
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj:_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.cpp:(.text+0x1ba):
undefined reference to `omp_destroy_nest_lock'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj:_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.cpp:(.text+0x1dc):
undefined reference to `omp_destroy_lock'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj:_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.cpp:(.text+0x1e8):
undefined reference to `omp_destroy_nest_lock'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj:_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.cpp:(.text+0x1f1):
undefined reference to `emlrtReportParallelRunTimeError'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj:_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.cpp:(.text+0x1f9):
undefined reference to `emlrtCleanupOnException'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj:_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.cpp:(.text+0x229):
undefined reference to `omp_get_num_procs'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_788353070741094_6308\_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.obj:_coder_grain_struct_grower_para_mex.cpp:(.text+0x246):
undefined reference to `emlrtCreateRootTLS'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Would be glad if somebody could tell me where the problem is.

Comment: Header files *declare* functions, they usually don’t *define* them. Definitions are typically in a library file, which you need to explicitly link against. Use the `l` option to the mex command for that. See my answer from earlier today here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65426452/7328782

Comment: ok, but how to find out which lib file I would need? The coder only gives me some cpp files where the header files are included. I dont know which lib files re required for the emlrt.h to tun

Comment: I hope someone will come along that knows this.

Comment: for the emlrt errors I linked the libemlrt.lib file i found in the lib folder and the error disappeared. know looking for the lib's needed for the omp errors

Comment: For OpenMP you need to add a compiler flag (`-fopenmp` for GCC). This should enable OpenMP and link all required libraries. See here how to add that through the `mex` function: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html#btw193g-1

Comment: Can you say more about why you need to manually edit the generated code? That's not a great workflow for many reasons. Maybe we can help you avoid that case.